# Why the closing button on the jQuery dialog is moved to the left while integrating with a Web Page?

Tags: jquery, html, button, dialog

I have a simple script for a dialog that basically works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () { $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body">
<div id="dialog" title="Message">
<p>Hello! Did you know you could save 2%</p>
</div>
</body>
```

However, integrating it onto some web sites sometimes does not work well.   Please see the difference on the link:
http://www.jboston.net/2013/Message1.png
How to fix moving the closing button to the left?

Firebug shows the following code for the button:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close" style="margin-right: 328.5px;"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button>
```

All styles are from jquery-ui.css except one style  coming from HTML: "margin-right: 328.5px;"

Comment: Check with a debugger tool which CSS rule gives this behaviour

Comment: Please, see the edited text of the question

Comment: `margin-right: 328.5px;` explain it for sure

Comment: this is from the button HTML that comes from jquery-ui: style="margin-right: 328.5px;">

Comment: you should provide a link which reproduce your issue. A way to exclude specific element shouldn't be hard to find

Comment: Sorry, cannot give the access to the whole production site.  Everything works fine on the small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I gave up using the jquery-ui dialog. It was possible to create the functionality I need using just jQuery  animate.

HTML:

```
<div id="admess" style="background: LightCyan; height: 150px; width: 400px; position: absolute;     display:none">
 <h3>title></h3>
 <h4>message></h4>
 <br/>
 <a id="closead" href="#">Close</a>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($("#admess").length)
{
         $("#admess").animate({
          left: $(window).width()/2 - $("#admess").width() / 2,
          top:  $("#admess").parent().height() / 2 - $("#admess").height() / 2,
          opacity: '1',
          height: '150px',
          width: '400px'
      });
         $("#admess").show();
 }

$("#closead").click(function () {
     $("#admess").hide();
 });
```